# Check if an ArrayList contains every element from another ArrayList

Tags: java, arraylist, comparison, contains

There is probably a simple one-liner that I am just not finding here, but this is my question:

How do I check if an ArrayList contains all of the objects in another ArrayList?  I am looking (if it exists) for something along the lines of:

```
//INCORRECT EXAMPLE:
if(one.contains(two))
{
    return true;
}
else
{
    return false;
}
```

For example:

```
ArrayList one = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5}

ArrayList two = {1, 2, 3} --> True
ArrayList two = {} --> True
ArrayList two = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5} --> True
ArrayList two = {1, 5, 2} --> True
ArrayList two = {1, 7, 4} --> False
ArrayList two = {0, 1, 3} --> False
ArrayList two = {4, 5, 6} --> False
ArrayList two = {7, 8, 9} --> False
```

Comment: in that case you want containsAll (already an answer)

Comment: And you can reduce your if statement to one line: `return one.containsAll(two);`

Comment: Related: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/382499/1889720

Answer (score 134, accepted):

There is a method called `containsAll` declared in the `java.util.Collection` interface. In your setting `one.containsAll(two)` gives the desired answer.

Answer (score 15):

Per the List interface:

```
myList.containsAll(...);
```

Answer (score 11):

Take a look at `containsAll(Collection<?> c)` method from `List` interface. I think it is what you are looking for.

Answer (score 9):

Here is another example use of containsAll() that I have used for asserting that two arrays are equal in JUnit testing:

```
List<String> expected = new ArrayList<String>();
expected.add("this");
expected.add("that");
expected.add("another");

List<String> actual = new ArrayListString();
actual.add("another");
actual.add("that");
actual.add("this");

Assert.assertTrue("The lists do not match!", expected.containsAll(actual));
```

Answer (score 5):

Your code in the example doesn't make sense, but here's an example anyway.

```
ArrayList<Integer> one, two;
//initialize
boolean good = true;
for (int i = 0; i < two.size(); i ++) {
    if (!(one.contains(two.get(i))) {
        good = false;
        break;
    }
}
```

It simply loops through all of `two`'s elements and checks to see if they are in `one`.

Then the boolean `good` contains the value you want.

See [ArrayList#contains](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#contains%28java.lang.Object%29).

**EDIT**: oh wow, I totally forgot [containsAll](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/AbstractCollection.html#containsAll%28java.util.Collection%29). Oh well, this is an alternate way to do it if you really want to understand it.

Comment: Once it goes 'false' you should 'break'. No need to keep checking the rest.

Comment: Alternatively (instead of break) you could do:
for (int i = 0; i < two.size() && good; i ++)

Comment: If you know that 'one' is ordered from small to large you could do a binary search in real code, but that would only help, timewise, if you expected 'one' to be pretty big.

Answer (score 5):

You can use `containsAll` method of the list to do the check. However, this is a linear operation. If the list is large, you should convert it to `HashSet` first, and then perform `containsAll`:

```
HashSet tmp = new HashSet(one);
if (tmp.containsAll(two)) {
    ...
}
```

If the length of `one` is `N` and the length of two is `M`, this solution has time complexity of `O(M+N)`; the "plain" `containsAll` has the complexity of `O(M*N)`, which may be significantly worse.

Answer (score 4):

This can also be done using streams in Java

```
    List<String> employeeList = Arrays.asList("Marc","john");
    List<String> masterEmployeeList = Arrays.asList("Marc", "Stacy", "john");
    System.out.println(employeeList.stream().allMatch(masterEmployeeList::contains));
```

Answer (score -1):

java.util.Collections.indexOfSubList(arrayListIS, arrayListIF)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -2):

isEqualCollection() method declared in the org.apache.commons.collections.CollectionUtils gives you the collections are same or not.

if (CollectionUtils.isEqualCollection(collectionA,collectionB))
{
do smt...
}