# HashSet.contains is returning false while it should not

Tags: java, hashset

I'm trying to learn Java, and I reached the HashSet part, Long story short I'm testing the contain method.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    HashSet<Integer> firstSet = new HashSet<>();
    firstSet.add(3);

    HashSet<Integer> secondSet = new HashSet<>();
    secondSet.add(3);

    boolean var = firstSet.contains(secondSet);

    System.out.println(var);

}
```

I believe this piece of  code should return true, while it is returning false. Any help!

Comment: [There is a difference between `contains` and `containsAll`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14511683/7366707). The first set definitely does not _contain_ the second set itself, while it _does_ contain all of the _elements_ of the second set.

Comment: You are checking if your first HashSet is containing not the values of second HashSet but HashSet itself, if instead of     firstSet.add(3); you did firstSet.add(secondSet), and your generic parameter for first set was <HashSet<Integer>> than your result would be true.

Comment: Yes, yes, I should have used containsAll instead of contains, Thank you..

Comment: If you want to check for a superset use `containsAll` as people have noted, but also note that for your two HashSets `firstSet.equals(secondSet)` will be `true`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
boolean var = firstSet.contains(secondSet);
```

This line is causing the problem, because you don't check presence of specific element from `secondSet`, you check if your `firstSet` stores **entire** `secondSet` in itself, which is obviously false.

You should have checked, for example, if it `. contains(secondSet.get(0))` or `.contains(3)`.

If your intention was to check if `firstSet` contains all elements that are present in the `secondSet`, you could use `firstSet.containsAll(secondSet)`.

Answer (score 5):

Let's look at the [docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/HashSet.html#contains(java.lang.Object)) for `contains`:

> Returns true if this set contains the specified element. More formally, returns true if and only if this set contains an element e such that `(o==null ? e==null : o.equals(e))`.

Since we all know that there is no null values here, we can say that `contains` will return true if `o.equals(e)`.

`o` is the parameter you pass to `contains`, which is a `HashSet`. `e` is the element of the first set, which should be an `Integer`. Since `Integer` and `HashSet` are unrelated types, it is very unlikely that they will equal.

You seem to have made a logical error here. To check if a set is a superset of another, call [`containsAll`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/AbstractCollection.html#containsAll(java.util.Collection)) instead:

> Returns true if this collection contains all of the elements in the specified collection.

Comment: You could then ask why `contains` takes an `Object` instead of an `E`, which would make this kind of mistake impossible: that's because of historical reasons and backward compatibility, because `HashSet` already existed before generics were added to Java. They couldn't change the `contains` method to take an `E` instead of an `Object`, because that would break backward compatibility.