# How to identify unique list of integers using set in Java

Tags: java, list, set

I am having list which consist of list of integers and would like to remove the duplicates from the parent list.

For example below are my list of int:-

```
{1,1,0}
{0,1,1}
{2,-1,0}
{0,-1,2}
{-1,0,2}
```

And I want to get the unique list from above which would be like below:

`{1,1,0} and {2,-1,0}` as other list are just the duplicate of these by arranging these int in some other order.

I tried to simply use the Set> but its not removing the duplicate list.

```
public class RemoveDuplicateList {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ArrayList<Integer> list = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(1, 1, 0));
        ArrayList<Integer> list1 = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(0, 1, 1));
        ArrayList<Integer> list2 = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(2, -1, 0));
        ArrayList<Integer> list3 = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(0, -1, 2));
        ArrayList<Integer> list4 = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(-1, 0, 2));
        Set<List<Integer>> set = new HashSet<>();
        set.add(list);
        set.add(list1);
        set.add(list2);
        set.add(list3);
        set.add(list4);
        System.out.println(set);
    }
}
```

> Actual O/P: [[-1, 0, 2], [2, -1, 0], [0, -1, 2], [1, 1, 0], [0, 1, 1]]
>
> Expected O/P: [[1, -1, 0],[2, -1, 0]]

Edit: I understand how Set works and how it internally uses HashMap to avoid the duplicates, I also tried creating my own class to hold these list of integers and overrides the equal method but didn't help, Maybe I should have override the hashcode as well, **I am just curious if there is an easy way to achieve this in Java.**

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14511655/check-if-an-arraylist-contains-every-element-from-another-arraylist-or-collecti this might help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it using the `Collection#removeIf`, just use a set which keeps track of the lists which were already added.

Now if you try to add another list having the same elements but in different order, that will fail and the `Set#add` will return `false` and that element will be removed from your main list:

```
List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(1, 1, 0));
List<Integer> list1 = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(0, 1, 1));
List<Integer> list2 = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(2, -1, 0));
List<Integer> list3 = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(0, -1, 2));
List<Integer> list4 = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(-1, 0, 2));

Set<List<Integer>> set = new HashSet<>(Arrays.asList(list, 
                                                     list1, 
                                                     list2,
                                                     list3, 
                                                     list4));
//keeps track of what was added before
 HashSet<Set<Integer>> added = new HashSet<>();

//converting the list to a set in the Predicate
//as you want to check the elements not their order
set.removeIf(l -> !added.add(new HashSet<Integer>(l)));

System.out.println(set);
```

Output:

```
[[1, 1, 0], [2, -1, 0]]
```

When you try to add a list to a set, not only will it check for the elements contained in the list you are trying to add but also the order. Since you have the same elements in certain lists in different order, the `list1.equals(list2)` becomes false as the order is different and it gets added in the set.

From the [docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/List.html#equals-java.lang.Object-):

> two lists are defined to be equal if they contain the
>   same elements in the same order.

**EDIT**

---

After looking at Andreas's comment I have fixed the code to work with lists having repeated elements like `[0, 0, 1] & [1, 1, 0]`. The earlier method would not include `[1, 1, 0]` in the output as in a set both `[1, 1, 0]` and `[1, 0, 0]` are the equal.

It can also be done using streams:

```
 List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(1, 1, 0));
 List<Integer> list1 = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(0, 1, 1));
 List<Integer> list2 = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(2, -1, 0));
 List<Integer> list3 = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(0, -1, 2));
 List<Integer> list4 = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(-1, 0, 2));
 List<Integer> list5 = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(0, 0, 1));
 List<Integer> list6 = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(1, 0, 0));

 Set<List<Integer>> set = new HashSet<>(Arrays.asList(list,
                                                     list1,
                                                     list2,
                                                     list3,
                                                     list4,
                                                     list5,
                                                     list6));


Set<List<Integer>> result = set.stream()
                               .map(l -> l.stream()
                                          .sorted()
                                          .collect(Collectors.toList()))
                               .collect(Collectors.toSet());

System.out.println(result);
```

Output:

```
[[-1, 0, 2], [0, 0, 1], [0, 1, 1]]
```

Comment: It's a great solution. But I want to understand "When you try to add a list to a set, not only will it check for the elements contained in the list you are trying to add but also the order. " , why so? Neither list nor set is sorted, then why this is happening?

Comment: @GauravJeswani The equals of the `ArrayList` is returning false for `list` and `list1` as it checks the elements contained in the list and also their order. So in this case the order is different

Comment: That doesn't work. Although `1,1,0` and `0,1,1` compares equal, `0,0,1` and `1,0,0` would also be equal to the first two, and that's not correct. You can't make the inner lists into sets, because you lose track of repeated numbers.

Comment: @Andreas sorry, I didn't think of that case. I have fixed it now.

Comment: @FullstackGuy, thanks for your prompt response, I am not much familier with streams, hence taking some time to understand it, would get back to you on this

Comment: Isn't `.flatMap(l -> Stream.of(xxx))` a long-winded way to say `.map(l -> xxx)`?

Comment: If input is `[[1, 0, 1], [1, 1, 0]]`, then second list is a duplicate, but this solution returns `[[0, 1, 1]]`, with is a list that isn't in the input.